# Convert list of fractions to numerical array

Tags: python, list, csv

I have data in the form of a list that looks like this:

```
'2/7,5/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,8131435000/20657804439,12526369439/20657804439,46/51,5/51,47240285000/61973413317,14733128317/61973413317\n',
'2/7,5/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1304992/3861431,2556439/3861431,46/51,5/51,8805032/11584293,2779261/11584293\n',
'2/7,5/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,251888/1212389,960501/1212389,46/51,5/51,3238088/3637167,399079/3637167\n'
```

How do I convert this to a matrix of numbers? Preferably using decimals instead of fractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```py
lines = [
    '2/7,5/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,8131435000/20657804439,12526369439/20657804439,46/51,5/51,47240285000/61973413317,14733128317/61973413317\n',
    '2/7,5/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1304992/3861431,2556439/3861431,46/51,5/51,8805032/11584293,2779261/11584293\n',
    '2/7,5/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,251888/1212389,960501/1212389,46/51,5/51,3238088/3637167,399079/3637167\n'
]

matrix = [[eval(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')] 
                   for line in lines]
```